# Client side translation from Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, octobercms

I am using October CMS with Laravel and have issues with client side translation and want to know if any of you possibly have any ideas how I could implement this.

I am using both the front-end translations via Twig `{{ 'String'|_ }}` for static content and also the laravel translation library for dynamic strings that are inserted into content on page load with `{{'author.plugin::lang.type.string'|trans  }}`.

Besides dynamically  inserting strings on page load, I am also doing this client side with Ajax. For example I have a search form with two `<select>` types, and the values and names of the second `<select>` depend on the value chosen in the first one.  However I can not simply put the javascript `var = value` into Twig like `{{ ( 'author.plugin::lang.type.string.'|trans  ~ value) }}` because Twig is executed on the Server. I will be very glad if anyone can suggest how I can handle this.

**Example Ajax Code**

```
function getTipNeprem(){

 $.ajax({
     method: 'get',
     url: '/sitename/vrsta_neprem=' + $("#vrsta_neprem").val(),
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){

        var tipi_nepremicnin = $.parseJSON(data[0].tip_nepremicnine_{{activeLocale}});
        var select_input = $("#tip_neprem");

        $(select_input).find("option").remove();
        $(select_input).append("<option value=''> {{ 'Choose Type'|_ }} </option>");

        $.each( tipi_nepremicnin, function( key, value ) {
            $(select_input).append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>").removeAttr("disabled");
        });

     }
 });
}
```

The issue is that the value of the option is always in the domestic language because it is the name of the column in the database used for the search function. If i use the ajax code in the above example it will always use only one language for both the value and content.`<option value="string in domestic_language"> string in foreign language </option>`

If you have a better idea how to implement this, I will be glad if you can point me in the right direction.